# Pybricks on Android Tablet

Tags: pybricks

I have a ZTE Grand View 4 Tablet (K87CA), 8 inch screen, Android 10,  with 2GB RAM, and the screen is blank when I go to https://code.pybricks.com/. Nothing happens.

Comment: What browser are you using? It should be one that is bluetooth compatible like Chrome or Chromium...Also, I'd like to note that using the pybricks webpages from a tablet is rather unorthodox usage, likely not tested very well or at all. You're supposed to write Python code on those webpages, so a device with at least a keyboard seems desirable.,

Comment: Chrome is the automatic choice on Android, so I use it. Bluetooth keyboards are easy enough to use as these have Bluetooth 4.2 Should not be a problem. For Power Functions App 8" screens are great. Don't understand why the web page doesn't load.

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug in Pybricks that caused an empty page to load for existing users when a new version was released. It should be fixed for new users, but existing users will need to clear the cache for this page:

**Windows**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

**MAC**

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

**Android**

You can clear the cache for specific pages with these steps:

- Go to settings in your browser
- Select *Site settings*
- Select *All sites*
- Use the search icon to search for *Pybricks*
- For each entry, click *Clear & reset*

[image: Android cache reset]